# Como selecionar um texto que não tenha um determinado termo no meio?

Tags: regex, exceção

Estou tentando selecionar uma parte de um código HTML com RegEx mas não estou conseguindo fazer a expressão regular correta, alguém poderia dar uma ajuda?

Preciso selecionar os grupos de `<li>` separadamente, ou seja, sem a presença da tag `<br>` no meio.

Por exemplo, estou tentando com a expressão abaixo:

```
/<li.*(?!<br).*\/li>/gi
```

E preciso selecionar o seguinte texto separadamente:

```
<li>Teste 1</li><li>Teste 2</li><li>Teste 3</li>
```

[Neste teste](http://refiddle.com/refiddles/5b1057cb75622d30084c0000), eu criei duas ocorrências dessa lista, porém a expressão está selecionando tudo desde a primeira ocorrência até a última.

Como faço para selecionar as duas listas separadamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema dos quantificadores `*` e `+` é que [eles são "gananciosos"](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap), ou seja, eles tentam pegar o maior número possível de caracteres que satisfaça a expressão.

Para cancelar este comportamento "ganancioso", basta [colocar um `?` depois do `*`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution). Com isso, a expressão pegará o mínimo de caracteres necessários (por isso `*?` também é chamado de *lazy quantifier*). Então a regex ficaria assim:

```
/<li.*?(?!<br).*?\/li>/
```

Você pode vê-la em funcionamento [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/wDN0l6/1).

---

A regex acima pega 6 grupos (cada tag `li`) separadamente. Para pegar uma sequência de vários `li` que não contém `br` como se fossem uma coisa só, basta buscar por 1 ou mais ocorrências de toda a regex anterior (usando o quantificador `+`):

```
(<li.*?(?!<br).*?\/li>)+
```

Você pode ver esta regex funcionando [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/SPE4pq/1).

Comment: Mas tem outro detalhe, eu queria que pegasse em 2 grupos e não cada item da lista (que dão as 6), não tem como?

Comment: Agora não estou no computador,  mas vejo assim que puder. De qualquer forma, acho que um parser de HTML talvez seja melhor do que regex

Comment: @RogerWolff Editei a resposta, acrescentando este outro caso (2 grupos em vez de 6)

Comment: Mas ainda acho melhor usar um parser de HTML/XML. Regex é legal, mas [não é a melhor ferramenta para fazer parsing de HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).