# Converter string com tags HTML em um array

Tags: javascript

Considere a seguinte string:

```
var texto = 'Esse é um texto de <span class="red"> teste </span>';
```

Preciso transformar a string em um array separando pelo espaço, ou seja:

```
var palavras = texto.split(" ");
```

O problema é que o texto contém HTML e nesse caso o array resultante será:

```
palavras[0] = 'Esse';
palavras[1] = 'é';
palavras[2] = 'um';
palavras[3] = 'texto';
palavras[4] = 'de';
palavras[5] = '<span';
palavras[6] = 'class="red">';
palavras[7] = 'teste';
palavras[8] = '</span>';
```

Porém necessito que o array resultante seja o seguinte:

```
palavras[0] = 'Esse';
palavras[1] = 'é';
palavras[2] = 'um';
palavras[3] = 'texto';
palavras[4] = 'de';
palavras[5] = '<span class="red"> teste </span>';
```

Como fazer isso utilizando javascript?

Comment: Usando expressão regular, tem que dividir por espacos exceto dentro de tags

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam o problema é criar essa expressão regular...

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) para fazer o parsing do texto HTML. A partir daí, basta manipular o HTML para obter os elementos que você precisa:

```js
// parsing do trecho HTML
var texto = 'Esse é um texto de <span class="red"> teste </span>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
// cria um document com html, header, body, etc
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(texto, "text/html");

// obter o body do HTML
var body = htmlDoc.querySelector('body');

// obter o elemento span
var span = body.querySelector('span');
// remover o span para que sobre só o texto
body.removeChild(span);
// quebrar o texto em um array
var palavras = body.innerHTML.trim().split(' ');
// adicionar o span no array
palavras.push(span.outerHTML);

console.log(palavras);
```

O código está bem específico para o texto que você colocou. Se tiver outras tags em outras posições, obviamente devem ser feitos os devidos ajustes.

---

Também é possível usar a função [`parseHTML` do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/). A ideia é a mesma: fazer o parsing e extrair os elementos que precisa.

```js
var texto = 'Esse é um texto de <span class="red"> teste </span>';
var html = $.parseHTML(texto);

var palavras;
$.each(html, function (i, el) {
    if (el.nodeName === '#text') {
        palavras = el.nodeValue.trim().split(' ');
    } else if (el.nodeName === 'SPAN') {
        palavras.push(el.outerHTML);
    }
});

console.log(palavras);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Novamente, o código é bem específico para o seu caso, pois espera um texto seguido de um `span`. Adapte para outros casos, se necessário.

---

*Regex, apesar de ser muito legal, nem sempre é a melhor solução, [principalmente para parsing de HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). Se já existem parsers específicos para o tipo de dado que você está manipulando, é preferível usá-los.*

Answer (score 4):

Com a mesma ideia apresentada pelo [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/325390/5878), você pode inserir o conteúdo da sua *string* em um elemento virtual e percorrer os elementos filhos. Se for uma instância de `Text`, efetua o *split*, caso contrário exibe o próprio conteúdo.

```js
function* get_elements(text) {
  const aux = document.createElement('div');
  aux.innerHTML = text;
  
  for (let element of aux.childNodes) {
    if (element instanceof Text) {
      yield* element.data.split(' ').filter(it => it);
    } else if (element instanceof HTMLElement) {
      yield element.outerHTML;
    }
  }
}

const elements = get_elements('Esse é um texto de <span class="red"> teste </span>')

console.log([...elements])
```

---

Uma solução análoga para o ES5 seria:

```js
function get_elements(text) {
  var result = [];  // criado um array para ser retornado
  var i;
  var aux = document.createElement('div');  // const virou var
  
  aux.innerHTML = text;
  
  for (i = 0; i < aux.childNodes.length; i++) {  // for..of virou for "clássico"
    if (aux.childNodes[i] instanceof Text) {  // element virou aux.childNodes[i]
      result = result.concat(  // coloca os pedaços do texto no resultado
        aux.childNodes[i].data.split(' ')
          .filter(
            function (it) {  // arrow function virou função anônima
              return it;
            }
          )
      );
    } else if (aux.childNodes[i] instanceof HTMLElement) {
      result.push(aux.childNodes[i].outerHTML);  // adiciona o html no resultado
    }
  }
  
  return result; // retorna o array final
}

var elements = get_elements('Esse é um texto de <span class="red"> teste </span>')

console.log(elements);
```

A ideia é exatamente a mesma, porém, ao invés de retornar um gerador, é retornado um *array*, bem como o laço `for..of` foi substituído pelo `for` "clássico" e a *arrow function* em `filter` substituída por uma função anônima.

Comment: Poderia dar uma solução com ES5? Nada contra o ES6, mas mesmo que as pessoas *gritem* e *saúdem* o ES6, IE11 e Androids antigos ainda vivem.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento feito.

Comment: Show! E ainda com explicação sobre as diferenças +1

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema. Não sei se é a melhor abordagem mas é uma solução que funciona. Aguardo sugestões.

Antes de separar por espaço, armazenei todas as tags e os respectivos conteúdos em um array e substituí cada posição pelo o respectivo index:

```
var texto = 'Esse é um texto de <span class="red"> teste </span>';

//verifica se existe alguma tag HTML
//output: ['<span class="red"> teste </span>'];
var tags = texto.match(/<(.*?)>.*?<\/(.*?)>/g); 

//se houver alguma tag, substitui pelo index correspondente
if(tags) {
    tags.forEach(function(tag, index) {
      texto = texto.replace(tag, "{"+index+"}");
    });
}
```

O resultado da string antes de separar por espaço será:

```
texto = 'Esse é um texto de {0}';
var palavras = texto.split(" ");
```

O resultado após separar por espaço será o seguinte array:

```
palavras[0] = 'Esse';
palavras[1] = 'é';
palavras[2] = 'um';
palavras[3] = 'texto';
palavras[4] = 'de';
palavras[5] = '{0}';
```

Agora basta substituir o elemento 5 que possui um index pela respectiva tag:

```
palavras.forEach(function(palavra, index) {
    //verifica se o elemento armazena o index correpondente a uma tag
    //e substitui o conteúdo pela tag
    if(palavra.match(/{[0-9]*?}/g))
        palavras[index] = tags[parseInt(palavra.replace(/{|}/g, ""))];
});
```

O resultado então será:

```
palavras[0] = 'Esse';
palavras[1] = 'é';
palavras[2] = 'um';
palavras[3] = 'texto';
palavras[4] = 'de';
palavras[5] = '<span class="red"> teste </span>';
```

Comment: Por que usar `*` seguido de `?`, o primeiro já é nenhum ou muitos, não seria redundante?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Na verdade o `?`, quando usado logo depois de `*` ou `+`, tem [outro significado](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy). Veja exemplos em que faz diferença usar `*` e `*?` [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/303472/112052) e [aqui](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap). No caso acima, é interessante usar para o caso de ter mais de uma tag, por exemplo

Comment: @hkotsubo não conhecia esse _lazy quantifier_, teria me ajudado umas semanas atrás, valeu